# How can I make this implementation even shorter?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I want to shorten this implementation.

```js
const person1 = {
  data: () => ({ name: 'Andrei' })
}

const users = [person1];

const parse = (doc) => {
  return (callback) => {
    return callback(doc.data())
  };
};

users.map(doc => parse(doc)(user => console.log(user)));
```

I am thinking something like this because the parse function already takes the parameter from map, but I don't know how to do it and if even it's possible.

```js
users.map(parse (user => console.log(user)));
```

Comment: Which line do you want to shorten exactly? Only the last one, and the rest is given?

Comment: It's simple, `console.log({name:'Andrei'})` gives same result :)

Comment: @Bergi yes, last one

Comment: @AndreiZgîrvaci Without changing the rest of the code, the only thing you can do is [replace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_conversion) the `user => console.log(user)` with `console.log`.

Comment: @Bergi I see, what if we change the rest of the code?

Comment: @AndreiZgîrvaci Then Endless has the answer - just throw away everything. Assuming you want to keep the `users` array, why not write `users.forEach(user => console.log(user.data()))` - what is the purpose of `parse`? How do you want to reuse it? Why do you use the array `map` method, do you expect any result?

Comment: @Bergi the thing is, that I will use user.data() multiple times after. But, I was actually just trying to figure out if there is a shorter way to do it, thank you! :)

I actually didn't know about `forEach`, I don't expect any result from the `map`, so it may be a better idea to use `forEach` instead.

Comment: Multiple times where? If you could give a real-world example, we could suggest some useful abstraction to shorten it.

Comment: @Bergi, For example, I have this situation all the time:

`const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get(); const data = await querySnapshot.data();`

Comment: Then wrap that in a function, as usual when you have duplicate code. Make it return a promise (like you already use it), don't pass a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the shortest way to solve this:

```js
const person1 = {
  data: () => ({ name: 'Andrei' })
}

const users = [person1];

function produce() {
  return function (doc) {
    return doc.data();
  }
}

users.map(
  produce(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
)
```

I used curried invocation for solving this problem, inspired from awsome library immmer.js -> https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/a9c0fd02c7575cfa6e61563e50a51ccc71949d9d/src/immer.js#L37

Comment: That makes no sense, `produce` doesn't take a parameter any more so the `console.log` function gets thrown away